# MIT OpenCourseWARE C/C++ Assignment 1 no output issue

Tags: c

I know very little about C/C++ so I decided to go through MIT's OpenCourseWare class online.  I did two years of Java classes about 8 years ago and I have about 4 years of recent experience with MATLAB.

After struggling to get the compiler setup, I manage to get the first lab completed in Eclipse IDE.  I can run both Hello World codes in Eclipse or cmd and they will output whatever text I have in the code.  I'm on 'Assignment 1' and I've made the modifications in the answer key to the .C files.

Here is the link to the assignment: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-s096-introduction-to-c-and-c-january-iap-2013/lectures-and-assignments/compilation-pipeline/

It appears to compile and generate the .exe, but when I go to the command prompt to enter the two inputs (int argc, char *argv[]), it runs but generates no output.  I'm using a command as suggested on the website: ./fibeverse 6 'what a trip that was!'.  There is only one warning in Eclipse, it is in fibverse.c and it says "unused variable 'i'" despite the variable being used in the two 'if' statements below.

I am using this line for my makefile: gcc -Wall -std=c99 fibeverse.c reverse.c fibonacci.c -o fibeverse

Does anyone know if I may be doing something incorrectly? I'm not sure if the error is how I am calling the .exe file or if the .exe was generated incorrectly.

I can post my exact text if desired, I don't want to clutter the post unless it's necessary.  I've reviewed the solution key several times to make sure I haven't mistyped anything.

Thanks for your time,

Ian

Edit: Here is the main, it doesn't post very nicely in the comments:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "fibonacci.h"
#include "reverse.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int i = 1;

#ifdef fibonacci
if (i < argc) {
    print_fib(atoi(argv[i]));
    i++;
}
#endif

#ifdef reverse
if (i < argc) {
    reverse(argv[i], strlen(argv[i]));
    i++;
}
#endif
printf("Press Enter to Exit\n");
getchar();

return 0;
}
```

The printf was added just to make sure it wasn't flashing the output, it responds no differently without it.  Also, the #ifdef were just changed to lowercase, but that didn't change anything either.

Thanks for the fast responses!

Comment: If it says the variable is unused, it's unused. You may be using a variable with the same name from another scope; hard to say without seeing your code. Of course an unused variable is just a warning, not an error, but it's generally a warning you should pay attention to. Odds are that your application of the changes was not exactly as the answer key intended.

Comment: You want me to post everything?  I was wondering if the variable problem was part of it.  It looks like if there was an error with 'i' it may just exit out of the if statements early.  The answer key has the exact text, I basically just copied and pasted.  So I don't think there may be any interpretation issues.

For now, here is my main, fibverse.c:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assignment 1 has two problems. In problem 1, the program should be compiled with `gcc -Wall -std=c99 fibeverse.c reverse.c fibonacci.c -o fibeverse`, and the errors that prevent the program from compiling should be fixed.

There are two errors:

- Each of `fibonacci.c` and `reverse.c` does not include its corresponding header, `fibonacci.c` and `reverse.c`. While a source file is not required to include its corresponding header, it is usually good practice for two reasons. One, the header declares routines that the source file defines, and including the header allows the compiler to see both declarations and definitions in the same compilation, which in turn allows the compiler to report inconsistencies between the two. Two, source files often use some of their own routines as subroutines, and including the header provides declarations for those routines, which are needed for routines that are used before they are defined. In `fibonacci.c`, `fib` is used before it is defined, so it should have a declaration before its use. Including `fibonacci.h` provides this declaration.
- `reverse.c` defines a routine named `backwards` but is intended to define a routine named `reverse`, so the name should be changed.

Once these errors are fixed, the program compiles, without error, using the command shown above.

That command is **only** for problem 1 of the assignment and should not be used for problem 2.

In problem 2, you modify the program so that the two pieces of code for calling `print_fib` or `reverse` can be separately enabled or disabled. As you have seen in the provided solution, this can be done by inserting statements such as `#ifdef FIBONACCI`.

Once you have made this modification, you enable each piece of code by including the switch `-DFIBONACCI` or `-DREVERSE` in the compiler command line. **Once you have made this modification, the original command line is not expected to work without complaint. Do not use it.**

The instructions for problem 2 show three commands to be used with the command after the program is modified.

This command builds the program so it only computes the Fibonacci number:

```
gcc -Wall -std=c99 -DFIBONACCI fibeverse.c reverse.c fibonacci.c -o fibonacci
```

This command builds the program so it only reverse the string:

```
gcc -Wall -std=c99 -DREVERSE fibeverse.c reverse.c fibonacci.c -o reverse
```

This command builds the program so it does both:

```
gcc -Wall -std=c99 -DFIBONACCI -DREVERSE fibeverse.c reverse.c fibonacci.c -o fibeverse
```

Comment: Thank you for your time Eric.  You're right, there was some confusion between the two problems.  I do believe you are correct in understanding the purpose of the assignment.  The main issue that still exists, is that if I don't manually change the #ifDef or #ifnDef statements, fibeverse.c will not recognize the FIBONACCI or REVERSE declarations in the compilation command and it ignores the whole block.  I was actually incorrect in the original post, I had been using 'gcc -Wall -std=c99 -DFIBONACCI -DREVERSE fibeverse.c reverse.c fibonacci.c -o fibeverse' to build the program without success.

Comment: @IanM.: The statements must be `#ifdef`, not `#ifDef`, and they must use all uppercase for the identifiers, as in `#ifdef FIBONACCI`, exactly matching the `-DFIBONACCI` used on the command line.

Comment: Right, `#ifdef`.  I did try them with all caps originally, such as `-DFIBONACCI`.  It seems like Eclipse doesn't recognize that I've used the `-DFIBONACCI` statements in the command line (I'm using a makefile instead though), so when it compiles, it treats the `fibeverse.c` file separate and doesn't run the `#ifdef` blocks.  Its definitely possible I'm not compiling them properly in Eclipse, rather than a problem with the files themselves.

Answer (score -1):

It's saying the variable is unused because it is. You've got ifdefs around both blocks of code where the variable i is used, but you are not defining the macros that are being tested.
At the top of the file, add:

```
#define fibonacci 1
#define reverse 1
```

You will see that the warning message disappears. You will also find that the for loops are now being executed.

Comment: The assignment calls for defining FIBONACCI and REVERSE via the command line. Defining them in the source is not the right solution.

Comment: Thanks!  That was the issue.  Why didn't they add that in the Solution?  I'll start learning how the syntax works for Macros.

Now it looks like there is an issue with Reverse.  It is only returning the first character: 
'what

Eric, what do you suggest is the problem?  I tried compiling them using 
    gcc -Wall -std=c99 -DFIBONACCI -DREVERSE fibeverse.c reverse.c 
fibonacci.c -o fibeverse

and that does not seem to work.

Comment: Okay, fixed the last problem.  I needed to input the string using " not '  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

I read the assignment. There are two C pre-processor constructs that you need to learn.

```
#ifdef foo
// Compile everything in this block if flag "foo" is defined in the program 
// or in the make file.
#end

#ifndef foo
// Compile everything in this block if flag "foo" is NOT defined anywhere.
#end
```

You can fix the compile time warning by replacing `#ifdef` with `#ifndef`. When you proceed to part two of the assignment, mix and match these constructs with compile time flags.

Comment: You're right, that was in the lecture.  Does these macros actually do anything?  I thought the purpose of a macro was to use the block somewhere else and save code.

Comment: In the C preprocessor, macros can also be tested and used to control whether part of the code should be compiled or not -- which is what `#ifdef  ... #endif` and `#ifndef ... #endif` (and #if ... #endif`) do. This is commonly used to select among several alternative solutions at compilation time, eg when different environments require different solutions or when experimenting with the code.

Comment: The assignment does not say to make any piece of code work if a symbol is **not** defined. There is no reason to use `#ifndef` in this assignment. The OP is getting an error message because they are using the wrong command (for Problem 1 of the assignment) to compile program after they have modified the program as required for Problem 2. The solution is to use the correct commands shown in the assignment for Problem 2.